# Qt: Widgets in text

Tags: qt, text

Is there any widgets to display text mixed with widgets? For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [x]consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut [v]labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, [image]quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

[x] and [v] - is a checkboxes, [image] - is a Graphics view.

Comment: You can use HTML tags inside QLabel's or QTextEdit's text. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

Comment: @user4419802 But there is no checkboxes and line edits. And I don't see any documentation about interaction text with code. Also, thanks, I forget about Rich Text Engine.

Comment: @Ivan what if you create the corresponding html page and try to load it into QWebView?

Comment: 'Input' tag is not supported, so no interaction is available. Perhaps, the only choice is QWebView as @vahancho suggested.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's easiest way to create HTML page and load it into QWebView. Thanks for idea, I will try.

Comment: @vahancho Can you post your answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in widget in Qt that supports such combination of text and other widgets. What you can try to do is composing `QLabel` widgets with text and other widgets in layouts, but it will be a nightmare to handle this composition if text dynamically changes or window resized.

From the other hand you present this composition as an html page and load it into `QWebView` which can serve as an almost fully functional web browser. You probably already saw such web pages for language tests where you need to input the correct words in empty edit boxes.